# What could be causing my top kakis' leaves to turn yellow and sick?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, fruit-trees, leaves

These two kaki were planted last year, and I was thinking there were doing pretty good.

But as you'll see on the pictures, leaves are really light green, and the topmost ones show brown and black spots or cracks... What could be doing this? What should I do?

From what I understood, the pH of the soil is not very important for this plant ( mine is calcareous). And I see no issue at the ground level on the little trunk...

My guess is some mineral deficiency. Any clue welcome.

[Kali leaves yellowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yMvI.jpg)
[image: Kali leaves yellowing]
[image: Kali leaves yellowing]

[Kali leaves yellowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABGRy.jpg)

Comment: is this Iron Chlorosis as [described here](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/persimmon-tree-yellow-dropping-fruit-91500.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored life to the plants with fertilizer (I used an organic preparation specialized for tomatoes from the store).

The first one below regained green colour, but the second (it got twice more fertilizer) realty sprouted beautiful branches, in less than a month!

So this might also have been iron chlorosis. I added acid soil for the first one to check.

[image: Persimmon, kaki regained a little life]

[image: Persimmon, kaki regained full life]

Hope this helps.